# Links between links in JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

Is there any way to link one link to another?
There is an [old question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MhOM.png) but no answer. Maybe something changed?

We need to create a link given on the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer in JointJS GitHub](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/1053)

> This is not supported yet. We're working on this though and hopefully this will be ready for the next big release.
>   Right now, you would need to create a tiny element between masterClass2 and LookUpClass2, which would be connected to the masterClass too.

**UPD:** in the same GitHub issue developers replied that it is now supported.

> It's now possible in v3.0.0.
>
> ```
> // for instance
> link1.target(link2, { anchor: { name: 'connectionPerpendicular' }});
> ```